# Pyside6 emitting different signals from the same worker thread

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyside6, pyqt6

I am using the QThread() and Worker() for longer tasks in my GUI.

I have a lot of different longer tasks that all should emit different Signals. Is it possible to perform these by using only one Worker class with different if clauses?

I already found out, how to submit the corresponding data to the Worker, but the problem is, that the Signal itself and the type of parameters it will emit has to be written before the initialization und also cannot be written in a dictionary. Is there any other way?

```
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = Signal(int)
    
    def __init__(self, task_to_perform=-1):
        super().__init__()
        self.task_to_perform = task_to_perform

    def next_calibration_step(self, perform_task=-1):
        print(f"performing task {perform_task}")
        self.finished.emit(5)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
...
    self.threadlist = {}
    self.next_thread += 1
    self.threadlist.update({self.next_thread: (QThread(), Worker(task_to_perform=1))})
    self.threadlist[self.next_thread][THREAD].started.connect(lambda: self.threadlist[self.next_thread][WORKER].next_calibration_step(self.threadlist[self.next_thread][WORKER].task_to_perform))
```

I was looking to add something like this in the worker class:

```
if task_to_perform == 0:
    finished = Signal(object, object)
elif task_to_perform == 1:
    finished = Signal(object, bool, object)
elif task_to_perform == 2:
    self.finished = Signal(object, object)
```

Comment: Why not just use multiple signals?

Comment: First of all, don't use lambdas for starting the threaded function. Then, if you want to identify the thread id and you need unidentified arguments, use a basic `Signal(int, object)`, then emit it using `self.task_to_perform` and a dictionary (or list/tuple) with the arguments. Note that: 1. you can probably just subclass QThread; 2. signals are initialized for the class, you cannot create signals for instances.

Comment: Regarding the lambdas I indeed noticed that simply sending the argument directly from the main thread to the new thread did not work and let the GUI freeze like if I didn't use a new thread. But using lambda to send the argument the worker will have after initialization to the worker worked for this part. Will this create problems later? Creating several signals actually does not create more lines of code. It just felt a bit dirty to create all of them every time.

Comment: How would it be possible to write it without the lambda function?